# Altering the middle point of the colors assigned to a scatterplot using a colorbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar

I have a simple scatter plot with a colorbar on the points as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

col1, col2, col3 = [], [], []
for i in range(0,21):
    col1.append(i)
    col2.append(i**1.5)
    col3.append(i)
    
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3': col3})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
im = ax.scatter(data['col1'], data['col2'], c=data['col3'], cmap='RdBu')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

The colorbar here automatically takes 10 as the middle point as the data of my `c` ranges from 0 to 20 and colors my points in the scatter plot accordingly, is there a way to assign the middle point of the colorbar yourself? For instance, making the middle point 5 rather than 10 in this example this way the white color would be assigned to 5 and the colorbar would still reach from 0 to 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass coustom [vmin, vmax, vcenter](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html#matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm) parameters while plotting. like so.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors


col1, col2, col3 = [], [], []
for i in range(0,21):
    col1.append(i)
    col2.append(i**1.5)
    col3.append(i)
    
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3': col3})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
norm = mcolors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=5)
  
im = ax.scatter(data['col1'], data['col2'], c=data['col3'], cmap='RdBu', norm = norm )
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Gives #

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify clearly, I strictly want to set a middle number such that the ends of the colorbar adapt, this way the white color would be assigned to 5 and teh colorbar would still reach 20.

Comment: Edited @BasR this what you looking for? If not not pls, post how your output should looks like...I'm very poor imaginating

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for yes, thank you